# This method is only adding one tag, but I want multiple tags!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tags

I have this method in my video model:

```
def assign_topics
  if @topic_names
    self.topics = @topic_names.map do |name|
      Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    end
  end
end
```

with `topic_names` as a virtual attribute. What this does it that every time I add a new topic, it seems to replace the old one with the new one. I don't want this to happen. I want it to add a new topic. How can I do this?

Note that it's not a problem with my associations. I've correctly implemented has_many through associations.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I figured it out:

```
def assign_topics
  if @topic_names
    self.topics << @topic_names.map do |name|
      Topic.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    end
  end
end
```